# Char * Pointers vs Integers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to compare two characters in C
But for some reason it is comparing an Integer, and a character. How can I convert a character pointer to an integer, so I can use it with the isspace() method?

Here is part of my code:

```
char *token;
token = strtok(line, " ");
int i = 0;
while (token != NULL)
{
    if(*token != ':' || isspace(token)){
        printf("%i:--%s--\n", i, token);
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int isspace(int ch)` expects a value in the `unsigned char` range or `EOF`.  It does not take a pointer as used by `char *token;  .... isspace(token)`

Instead reference the `char` pointed to by `token`.  As `char` may be as `signed char` or `unsigned char`, insure `unsigned char` values are used when passed to `is...()` functions.

```
// isspace(token)
isspace((unsigned char) *token)
```

---

`if(*token != ':' || ...){` is strange as that passes all non-`':'` characters, which includes all white-space ones.  This portion of OP's code is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You already do it correctly with `*token != ':'`. Just use the same syntax: `isspace(*token)`.